# how to write less mixin for states like :hover, : active, :disabled?

Tags: less, less-mixins

This is how I wrote it, but I get

> Parse Error: Unrecognised Input

How can I circumvent this?

I do not want to declare individual mixin for focus, active and disabled states.

I am using WinLess for compiling on Windows 7.

- WinLess version:1.9.1
- Less.js version:2.1.2

Here is my code

```
.state(@state,@property,@colour){
    &:@{state}{
        @{property}:@colour;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you upgrade to the latest version of the compiler? The code should work fine as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **best solution to is to update your Less.js compiler** to the latest version (v 2.5.3) because it compiles the code provided in the question as-is without the need for any modifications.

However, if you can't upgrade the compiler for whatever reasons then you would need an intermediate variable to form the pseudo-class selectors and then use them like in the below snippet:

```css
.state(@state,@property,@colour){
  @sel: ~":@{state}";
  &@{sel}{
    @{property}:@colour;
  }
}
#demo{
  .state(hover,color,red);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Harry. I am trying to upgrade winless less.js file, but I am afraid I might get some errors.